# How to filter posts [products] that belong to a specific category

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to filter the products on my website in different categories. For example, if you select the category "DRINKS", it will show me the products that belong to that category.

To explain myself better.

I need the publications [products] of my website to be filtered by categories, for example when selecting a category say "DRINKS" only the publications [products] that belong to that category are shown.

DATABASE [IMAGES]

**CATEGORIES**

[image: database categories image]

**POSTS [PRODUCTS]**

[image: database post [product] image]

For example, when selecting the "Drinks" category, only the products marked with this category are shown, in this case "Product"

This is my code currently:

**Code showing products within categories.php [index]**

```
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/app/controllers/products.php');
include('app/includes/categories.php');
$categorias = selectAll('categories');
$capitulos = selectAll('products');

<div class="productos-list">
    
<?php foreach ($productos as $key => $producto): ?>           
<ul>
    <a href="/ver/productos.php?id=<?php echo $producto['id']?>">
    <li class="producto-name"><?php echo $producto['name']?></li>
    </a>
</ul>
<?php endforeach; ?> 
    </div>
```

**PRODUCTS.PHP**

```
<?php 

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/app/database/db.php');
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/app/helpers/validatePost.php');

$table = 'posts';
$categorias = selectAll('categorias');

$errors = array();
$id = '';
$title = '';
$productos = '';
$categoria_id = '';

$productos = selectAll($table);


if (isset($_POST['add-post'])) {
    $_POST['topic_id']=serialize($_POST['topic_id']);
    $errors = validatePost($_POST);
    
    if (!empty($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
        $image_name = time() . '_' . $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $destination = "../../images/" . $image_name;
        
        $result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $destination);
        
        if ($result){
            $_POST['image'] = $image_name;
        } else {
            array_push($errors, "¡Algo fallo al subir la imagen!");
        }
        
        
    } else {
      array_push($errors, "¡Necesitas subir una imagen!");
    }
    
    if (count($errors) === 0){
        unset($_POST['add-post']);
        $post_id = create($table, $_POST);
        $_SESSION['message'] = '¡Post creado correctamente!';
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
        header('location: ../../admin/posts/index.php');
        exit();
    } else {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $topic = $_POST['categoria_id'];
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $post = selectOne($table, ['id' => $id]);
}

if (isset($_GET['del_id'])){
    $id = $_GET['del_id'];    
    $count = delete($table, $id);
    $_SESSION['message'] = '¡Post eliminado correctamente!';
    $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
    header('location: ../../admin/posts/index.php');
    exit();
}

if (isset($_POST['update-post'])){
    $errors = validateEdit($_POST); 
    
    if (count($errors) === 0){
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        unset($_POST['update-post'], $_POST['id']);
        $post_id = update($table, $id, $_POST);
        $_SESSION['message'] = '¡Post actualizado correctamente!';
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
        header('location: ../../admin/topics/index.php');
        exit();        
    } else {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $topic = $_POST['categoria_id'];
}
} 
?>
```

**CATEGORIES.PHP**

```
<?php 

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/app/database/db.php');
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/app/helpers/validateCategoria.php');

$table = 'categorias';

$errors = array();
$id = '';
$name = '';
$title = '';
$productos = '';
$categoria_id = '';

$categorias = selectAll($table);


if (isset($_POST['add-post'])) {
    $errors = validateCategoria($_POST);
    
    if (count($errors) === 0){
        unset($_POST['add-post']);
        $post_id = create($table, $_POST);
        $_SESSION['message'] = '¡Categoria creada correctamente!';
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
        header('location: ../../admin/categorias/index.php');
        exit();
    } else {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $post = selectOne($table, ['id' => $id]);
}

if (isset($_GET['del_id'])){
    $id = $_GET['del_id'];    
    $count = delete($table, $id);
    $_SESSION['message'] = '¡Categoria eliminada correctamente!';
    $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
    header('location: ../../admin/categorias/index.php');
    exit();
}

if (isset($_POST['update-post'])){
    $errors = validateEdit($_POST); 
    
    if (count($errors) === 0){
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        unset($_POST['update-post'], $_POST['id']);
        $post_id = update($table, $id, $_POST);
        $_SESSION['message'] = '¡Categoria actualizada correctamente!';
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
        header('location: ../../admin/categorias/index.php');
        exit();        
    } else {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];

}
} 
?>
```

**DB.PHP**

```
<?php

session_start();
require('connect.php');

function dd($value)
{
    echo "<pre>", print_r($value, true), "</pre>";
    die();
}


function executeQuery($sql, $data)
{
    global $conn;
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $values = array_values($data);
    $types = str_repeat('s', count($values));
    $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$values);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt;
}


function selectAll($table, $conditions = [])
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table";
    if (empty($conditions)) {
        $sql = $sql . " ORDER BY id DESC";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $records;    
    } else {
        // $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE username='ElVictox' AND admin=1";
        
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($conditions as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " WHERE $key=?";
                
            } else {
                $sql = $sql . " AND $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }
        
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $values = array_values($conditions);
        $types = str_repeat('s', count($values));
        $stmt->bind_param($types, $values);
        $stmt->execute();
        $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $records;
    }
}



function selectOne($table, $conditions)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table ";

        $i = 0;
                foreach ($conditions as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " WHERE $key=?";
                
            } else {
               $sql = $sql . " AND $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }
        $sql = $sql . " LIMIT 1";
        $stmt = executeQuery($sql, $conditions);
        $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        return $records;
    }

function create($table, $data)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table SET ";
      
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " $key=?";
                
            } else {
                $sql = $sql . ", $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }
    $stmt = executeQuery($sql, $data);
    $id = $stmt->insert_id;
    return $id;
    
}

function update($table, $id, $data)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "UPDATE $table SET ";
      
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " $key=?";
                
            } else {
                $sql = $sql . ", $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }
    
    $sql = $sql . " WHERE id=?";
    $data['id'] = $id;
    $stmt = executeQuery($sql, $data);
    return $stmt->affected_rows;
    
}


function delete($table, $id)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "DELETE FROM $table WHERE id=?";
      
    $stmt = executeQuery($sql, ['id' => $id]);
    return $stmt->affected_rows;
    
}
```

**EDIT:**  I don't have errors to show the products in the category, what I want to do is show them specifically in their category. For example, I select the category "Drinks" and I want it to show me only the drink products.

Currently it happens to me that all products are shown in all categories, for example in the "Drinks" category all products are shown, including those that do not belong to it.

Comment: Read your error logs. From here that first snippet looks like every variable is not set. Where are your includes or requires?

Comment: @StackSlave | I don't have errors to show the products in the category, what I want to do is show them specifically in their category. For example, I select the category "Drinks" and I want it to show me only the drink products. | Currently it happens to me that all products are shown in all categories, for example in the "Drinks" category all products are shown, including those that do not belong to it.

Comment: You selected all categories, what do you expect?

Comment: This is your solution https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: @Heimdalssidstevogter | Thanks for the solution, but sorry I have a question, what would I have to change in the code? I am new to this and I have many doubts

Comment: @VictorHugo no worries. gonna write it as an answer

Comment: @Heimdalssidstevogter Perfect, very thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a join using. example with mysqli

file1.php

```
<?php
        $db = new mysqli(ip,username,password,db);
        $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products INNER JOIN categorias ON product.categoria_id = categorias.id WHERE categorias.name = ?");
        $query->bind_param("s",$categoria);
        $query->execute();
        $coll = $query->get_result();
        $query->store_result();
        $elements = [];
        while ($row = $coll->fetch_assoc()){
           $elements[] = $row; // products where categorias.name = $categoria
        }
?>
```

index.php

```
  <?php 
include "file1.php";

foreach ($elements as $element){
echo $element["name"];
}
?>
```

Comment: It gives me this error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param()

Comment: That's because the table values in the query's aren't the same as in your db ;)

Comment: Done It's works, and excuse me, but one last question, how can I get the products to print in my index.php?

Comment: @VictorHugo i just changed the solution above. just include the file and then you can loop the value $elements that contains your sorted table values. Remember to mark as your solution and upvote ;)

Comment: @VictorHugo upvooote

Comment: I already added it but nothing is shown, and I vote for you but it tells me that it does not appear because I am not level 15